# linux - bash - get usage processor cores like htop

Tags: linux, cpu

I want to get my processor cores usage like displayed in htop.
Data will be taken by command line or system file, processing with php,

thanks

PS : excuse my bad english

Comment: then use either htop or top (option 1) or just trail/grep from /proc/cpuinfo ; what do you really want to do ??

Comment: hi,
François is a french first name. Are you french ? I am, it will be easier for me to explain in french